# Level design - modular vs single project

Tags: blender, level-design

I'm working in Blender and UE4 for a while now...

I always have the dillema of how to create my levels. My two ideas are:
a) modular - like lego blocks. Create a wall, a floor, wall with hole for a window etc inside blender, and then, in UE4 make a level out of them. The advantage here is that I can arrange them however I want. The disadvantage is - I always have a problem getting the elements to fit properly. Even if I scale one element up or down, everything else starts falling apart.

b) single project - make a whole object like a room or house in blender. Then everything connects nicely, but I'm always worried that it will be harder to edit, and I usually end up messing something. For example, whole house looks great, but inside the game a window is way too high, or the doors are too narrow to go through.

My question:
What should I do - should I stick to one method and try to fix the disadvantage? If yes, how would I do that? Is one of the methods considered "better" or the "industry standard"?

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything is done modular for a number of reasons. This spans from the reducing polygons on hit boxes too supporting asset recycling to cut down on work. This is no means to say that large or complex assets are bad are shouldn't be used but building things modular then fixing the problems later in an editor is almost always more efficient.

I would also note that on single person projects, in my experience, it is best to make temp assets then later, once levels are built, already modular, make the assets for current and future use.